# Documentation / Example of xquery for ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to parse a xml file using xquery in Ruby, I found this lib [ruby-xquery](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-xquery). But it is not well-documented. Could anyone please show me some example how to use the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that xquery is maintained, I would recommend looking into Nokogiri for parsing and working with xml. It is easy to use, there are a lot of examples out there and it is documented extremely well.

```
http://nokogiri.org/

http://nokogiri.org/tutorials
```

There is even a Railscast on using nokogiri :)

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri/
```

Answer (score 2):

The Zorba XQuery processor has also a ruby binding: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/documentation/2.5.0/ruby/ruby_test_8rb-example

For instance, the application at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo is powered by ruby on rails. The source code is available at https://code.launchpad.net/~zorba-coders/zorba/web-try.zorba-xquery.com